# How to parse a parameter in a URI for use in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to use the ID present in the route
 `post 'users/:id/contacts/create' => 'contacts#create'`. I am trying to parse the ID by `params[:id]`. As shown below, in my contact controller:

```
      def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      render json: @contact, status: :created, location: @contact
    else
      render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The contact params function is:

```
    def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit( :name, :email, :phone, :user_id=>params[:id])
end
```

However, when I am posting the data, the :user_id is returning as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
def contact_params
  params[:contact][:user_id] = params[:id]
  params.require(:contact).permit( :name, :email, :phone, :user_id )
end
```

Comment: Perfect! **Thank you so much, @Yang.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to change the id parameter route to [nested](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) because it is not the primary object/resource of the ContactsController

```
resources :users do
  resources :contacts, as: 'users_contacts'
end
```

Then run bundle exec rake routes CONTROLLER=users

Should print how its setup.

I think your parameters should then appear as you want them

```
 params.require(:contact).permit( :name, :email, :phone, :user_id)
```

Remember you also want to do this so as to follow the rails way. Any deviation from standard way will make things complex unnecessarily in future.

As a suggestion try generating a default scaffold controller with routes done like that.

```
rails g scaffold_controller Contacts
```

That should have this object saved via post in the code and a sneak peak at the parameters.

Hope it helps.